# Syncfusion TreeGrid and Grid with WebAPI doesn't work on delete

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, syncfusion

I've set up a treeGrid (the grid is the same) to get data through the ASP.NET WebAPI using their DataManager:

```
var categoryID=15;
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/API/myrecords?categoryID=" + categoryID,
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor()
});

$("#treeGridContainer").ejTreeGrid({
    dataSource: dataManager,
    childMapping: "Children",
    treeColumnIndex: 1,
    isResponsive: true,

    contextMenuSettings: {
        showContextMenu: true,
        contextMenuItems: ["add", "edit", "delete"]
    },
    contextMenuOpen: contextMenuOpen,
    editSettings: { allowEditing: true, allowAdding: true, allowDeleting: true, mode: 'Normal', editMode: "rowEditing" },

    columns: [
        { field: "RecordID", headerText: "ID", allowEditing: false, width: 20, isPrimaryKey: true },
        { field: "RecordName", headerText: "Name", editType: "stringedit" },

    ],

    actionBegin: function (args) {
        console.log('ActionBegin: ', args);
        if (args.requestType === "add") {
            //add new record, managed manually...
            var parentID = 0;
            if (args.level != 0) {
                parentID = args.parentItem.TaxonomyID;
            }
            args.data.TaxonomyID = 0;
            addNewRecord(domainID, parentID, args.data, args.model.selectedRowIndex);
        }
    }
});
```

The GET works perfectly.

The PUT works fine as I'm managing it manually because it's not called at all from the DataManager, and in any case I want to manage the update of the records in the TreeGrid.

The problem is with DELETE, that is called by the DataManager when I click Delete from the context menu over an item in the TreeGrid.

It makes a call to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:50604/API/myrecords?categoryID=15/undefined
```

and obviously, I get a **405 (Method Not Allowed)**

The problem is given by the categoryID parameters that break the RESTful schema, and the DataManager is not able to understand that there is a parameter.

A possible solution could be to send this parameter as a POST variable but the DataManager is not able to do it.

Does anyone have a clue of how to solve it? it's a common scenario in real-world applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While populating Tree Grid data using ejDataManger, CRUD actions will be handled using inbuilt Post (insert), Put (update), Delete requestType irrespective of CRUD URL’s. So, no need to bind ‘removeUrl’ for deleting records.

And, in the provided code example parameter is passed in the URL to fetch data hence the reported issue occurs. Using ejQuery’s [addParams](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejquery#methods:addparams) method we can pass the parameter in URL. You can find the code example to pass the parameter using Tree Grid [load](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtreegrid#events:load) event and the parameter is retrieved in server side using DataManager.

```
[html]  
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({ 
            url: "api/Values",          
            adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor() 
        });  
        $("#treeGridContainer").ejTreeGrid({ 
            load: function (args) { 
                // to pass parameter on load time 
                args.model.query.addParams("keyId", 48); 
            }, 
  }); 

[controller] 
public object Get() 
        { 
            var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString; 
            // here we can get the parameter during load time 
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(queryString["keyId"]);                    
                //.. 
           return new {Items = DataList, Count = DataList.Count() }; 
        }
```

You can find the [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/webapiadaptor-817646255) here for your reference.

Regards,

Syncfusion Team